# msdeploy: deploy reference of reference

Tags: msdeploy

is there a way for msdeploy to figure out reference of reference?
for example, i have project B that references project A that references TFS assemblies.
On my dev machine, TFS assemblies are GACed with Visual Studio installation, but my server doesn't have VS installed so it isn't GACed.
msdeploy doesn't seem to understand that it has to copy both assembly A and TFS assemblies that assembly A references.

I believe it is by design that VS ignores 'CopyLocal' if the assembly is GACed and i know that i can work around it by adding the assembly directly into the project but i am looking for more automatic way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the TFS API Nuget package to reference these assemblies instead of the GAC.

[Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)